# Convert localized string into decimal in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a decimal, that could look like `123,34`, `123123,09`, `1234`, `123.34`, `123123.09`.

My MVC application supports localization, I need to find a safe way to convert the most likely user input into a decimal. So for decimal value `.` will represent as `,` (e.g 12.34 => 12,34)

I want to get this value in javascript as

```
var maxAmount = parseFloat("@Model.MaxAmount");
```

if MaxAmount is `1,25` I will get a result as `1` only.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not specify the format for the model property using MaxAmount.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) - that way the decimal will always be serialized as 1.25 and still be properly interpreted by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the replace for the edge case of `xxx,xx`:

```
var maxAmount = parseFloat('@Model.MaxAmount'.replace(',', '.'));
```

This will convert string of type `"123,45"` to `"123.45"` but keep the `"123.45"` in the same format.

Comment: The value will not contain , only... It is culture specific amount.. other character will be there to represent decimal.

Comment: @user You'd better provide different examples of what the decimal delimiters are.